# Unity OBJExporter gives Null Reference Exception

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the EditorOBJExporter script for Unity found here:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjExporter

But I appear to get this error upon using the script:

```
NullReferenceException
EditorObjExporter.MeshToString (UnityEngine.MeshFilter mf, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 materialList) (at Assets/Editor/EditorObjExporter.cs:68)
EditorObjExporter.MeshesToFile (UnityEngine.MeshFilter[] mf, System.String folder, System.String filename) (at Assets/Editor/EditorObjExporter.cs:196)
EditorObjExporter.ExportWholeSelectionToSingle () (at Assets/Editor/EditorObjExporter.cs:297)
```

I am using Unity version 4.1.2f1, I have tried downgrading my Unity version to numerous other versions. Nothing I do makes the script not result in the Null Reference Exception.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks in advanced.